# Load an .ico file as a Bitmap in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show the favicon's from other domains in a tool on my site so I can show each domain's "logo". There's a great web app to extract the favicon for you because identifying the URL for the favicon can be tricky: http://getfavicon.appspot.com/

For example (I can't embed it here because it's an .ico file):
http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://stackoverflow.com

The problem is, the .ico files from various domains are in various sizes and I'd like to cache them locally in a specific size using .png format.

After researching, I found this can be accomplished using the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.IconBitmapDecoder` class, but it relies on `WindowsBase`, `System.Xaml` and `PresentationCode` - all things I don't want to use from an asp.net application.

Is there another way to convert .ico files to .png using c# from an aspx page?

Comment: The alternative built-in way is `System.Drawing` and that's even worse to use from ASP.NET.

Comment: System.Drawing wouldn't actually bother me, but I don't think it supports .ico?

Comment: It does support it with the [`System.Drawing.Icon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.aspx) class. However MSDN [recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) using WIC instead. The `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace (the one you are trying to avoid) [uses WIC](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowswic/thread/eb12e493-257d-481d-bd28-a0f232dc52e5/).

Comment: How about async the .png creation to a web service and populate the generated image on callback? That would abstract the code away from your web app.

Comment: IIRC using GDI for in an asp.net web app is a race-condition waiting to happen (unless you dedicate a single thread to the job... it's not made to be called from different threads)